# Как предотвратить запуск майнеров из Tomcat?

Tags: windows, tomcat, вирусы

Стоят Томкаты 7.0.47 (обновить - не вариант) на Windows 2012/16
Вроде как с  дефолтной настройкой.

Периодически какой-нибудь из них начинает запускать cmd, который создает powershell, который качает очередной майнер откуда-то извне.

Это разные cmd с разными ps, которые качают разные майнеры, с разными адресами и у эксплойтов разные принципы запуска и воздействия на систему.

Вывод - есть какая-то дыра, о которой знают все китайские кулхацкеры, но о которой не знаю я.

В томкатах ни в зуб ногой. Все советы в документации по безопасности касаются linux.
Куда копать на винде? Дайте подсказку, разберусь, выложу "инструкцию" по закрытию.

Comment: Стандартные процедуры уже делал? Накатить все обновы для винды, проверить машины хотя бы `cureit`'ом, закрыть все порты на внешку, кроме реально необходимых.

Comment: Ну и по-хорошему конечно надо всё переставить, потому что хрен его знает какие УЖЕ есть бэкдоры.

Comment: Не думаю что защита томката на винде и на линуксе как-то принципиально различаются.

Comment: Проблема не в винде, а в томкате, я гарантирую это.
Отличия от линукса есть. Может они не столь критичны как мне кажется? Я перепроверю.
Кука и лог, спасибо, покурю их.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, про линукс не было сказано ни слова.

Comment: @donRumata цитирую автора вопроса: *"Все советы в документации по безопасности касаются linux."*

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а, протупил.